# How to use if statement conditional in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, time

I want to show a status whether the shop is open or close based on current time. So here is the code.

In controller

```
$http.get(httpUrl + 'shops/get_shops')
.then(function (returns) {
   $scope.shops = returns.data;
});
var now = new Date();
$scope.current_time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':00';// to get hh:mm:ss format
```

In the view

```
<div ng-repeat="item in shops">
   <span ng-if="item.open_hour != '00:00:00' && item.open_hour <= '{{current_time}}' && item.close_hour >= {{current_time}}">We're open</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the result is only meet the first condition `item.open_hour != '00:00:00'` and the rest are disobeyed. So all the data which have open_hour not '00:00:00' will be open regardless the open_hour and close_hour.

I'm new to angularjs and don't know how to do thing like this. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `<span ng-if="{{item.open_hour != '00:00:00' && item.open_hour <= 'current_time' && item.close_hour >= current_time}}">We're open</span>` change to this

Comment: @HardikVaghani your answer it's wrong. `item.open_hour <= 'current_time'`  → current_time it's a scope var not a string.

Comment: @HardikVaghani that's work!! but I think it should be without quote in current_time. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in `ng-if` you don't need `{{}}` for getting a scope var.

```
<span ng-if="item.open_hour != '00:00:00' && item.open_hour <= current_time && item.close_hour >= current_time">We're open</span>
```